# Tradeoffs in translation-invariant tilings of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

Suppose I tile $\mathbb{R}^3$ in a ($\mathbb{Z}^3$-)translation-invariant manner.  If we insist on the tiling being regular, then we are left with only the cubic tiling.  However, suppose that we allow for any finite number of symmetry-inequivalent flags.  Then, I'm curious what tools there are to determine relations between the four quantities:

1) Average vertex degree

2) Average number of edges in a face

3) Average number of faces incident to an edge

4) Average number of faces in a volume.

Comment: May I ask: What is a "regular tiling"? Tiling by regular polyhedra? And could you expand upon the phrase "symmetry-inequivalent flags."?

Comment: Sorry that the question isn't clear.  When I say tiling, I mean one in the most general sense: a regular CW-filtration of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  The tiling gives us a discrete group of isometries that preserves the filtration.  This group action partitions the flags into equivalence-classes, and a regular tiling is, to me, one that only has a single equivalence class.  

For this question, any partition of space (into non-convex bodies or otherwise) is allowed, so long as its translation invariant.

Comment: By translation invariant, presumably you mean that there exists a full-rank sublattice of the set of translations on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the tiling is fixed under translations in the sublattice. We would call such a tiling *periodic*. I believe if you mod out $\mathbb{R}^3$ by this lattice (or some sublattice of that so that you don't identify too many $n$-cells together) and consider the induced tiling of the torus, then all the quantities you consider will be reflected there.

Comment: That's correct.  I'm equivalently interested in tools for relating these values in any regular CW-decomposition of the $3$-torus.

Comment: Well once everything is in the torus, then you can start using Euler characteristic arguments and homology to relate these quantities .

Comment: This is certainly true, thanks! I guess I'm interested in more fine-grained bounds, but this is definitely the right way to phrase the problem.  I've posted a more general follow-up question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346768/flag-f-vectors-of-cw-complexes.