# Flag $f$-vectors of CW-complexes

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics

Hidden away in the appendix of this nice paper by [Björner and Kalai](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485890544), they give a clean description of $f$-vectors that can arise from regular CW-complexes in terms of truncations of the Euler-Poincaré characteristic.

I'm curious if similar characterizations exist for their generalized version, flag $f$-vectors?  My initial motivation was [this simpler question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346706/tradeoffs-in-translation-invariant-tilings-of-mathbbr3), but now I'm curious what is known in the general case.